# How to use what the user input for an array size from the main method?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to create a program that measures the time it takes for each sorting algorithm to sort random integers in an array. The problem is in my main class I ask the user to input what the size of the array should be. However, I'm trying to pass this number "arraySize" into another class.

For now, I set the size of the array as 50.

So, the program should work by taking in array with a size of input.next() and then populates the array with random integers. It then sorts the array and measures the time.

This is my main:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
      { 

      // final int was set earlier in the assignment to 50. Therefore
      //the program will only take an answer for a size n of 50.

      System.out.println("Please enter the size of array:");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
      int arraySize =input.nextInt();    

        initValues();
        printValues();
        System.out.println("values is sorted: " + isSorted());
        System.out.println();

        // make call to sorting method here (just remove //)

         /**long startTime = System.nanoTime();
         long total = 0; 
         selectionSort(); 
         long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
         long elapsedTime = stopTime-startTime;
         */

         long startTime = System.nanoTime();
         long total = 0;
         bubbleSort();
         long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
         long elapsedTime = stopTime-startTime;

        printValues();
        System.out.println("values is sorted: " + isSorted());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The time it took to sort was: " +elapsedTime); 
      }
     }
```

This is in same class as my main:

```
public class Sorts
{
  static  int SIZE =50;            // size of array to be sorted
  static int[] values = new int[SIZE];   // values to be sorted

  static void initValues()
  // Initializes the values array with random integers from 0 to 99.
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
      values[index] = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % 100;
  }

  static void selectionSort()
  // Sorts the values array using the selection sort algorithm.
  {
    int endIndex = SIZE - 1;
    for (int current = 0; current < endIndex; current++)
      swap(current, minIndex(current, endIndex));
  }
```

Why can't I replace SIZE with arraySize? Is there a way where I can declare SIZE as my input.nextInt() in my main method? If I do that, it still populates the array with 50 random integers.

Comment: You should be able to use arraySize, assuming it's declared properly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "This is in the same class as my main".  Is your `main` _inside_ the `Sorts` class, or is `Sorts` a nested class inside some other class that also contains `main`?  I think we need to know before we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: if  I declare arraySize in my main it still populates the array with 50 random integers. Main is in the class Sorts.